# Dividir texto en varios textos

Tags: php

necesito separar un texto en partes (array). El texto similar a este:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget
>   magna faucibus, fermentum nibh dapibus, dictum.
>
> Integer eleifend lorem nec velit tincidunt, eu elementum nulla cursus.
>
> [Separador1]Donec arcu quam, posuere non molestie eu, bibendum non
>   enim.[/Separador1]
>
> Phasellus ante nulla, euismod vitae magna porta, iaculis posuere
>   velit.
>
> [Separador2]Mauris sed fermentum justo, at hendrerit sem.
>   [/Separador2]
>
> Cras dapibus magna vel urna facilisis, sed fringilla urna interdum. In
>   posuere sed nibh sed pharetra.

Lo he realizado con preg_match_all de la siguiente manera:

```
$re = '/\[Separador1\](.*?)\[\/Separador1\]|\[Separador2\](.*?)\[\/Separador2\]/ms';
preg_match_all($re, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

Sin embargo el resultado contiene solo lo que está dentro de [Separador1]...[/Separador1]  y [Separador2]...[/Separador2]  pero necesito que el resultado en array también contenga el texto que está encima de [Separador1] y [Separador2]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método explode de `php`. Esta función necesita cuál es el separador por el que quieres dividir y el texto que quieres dividir.

```
$txt = "Hola,Hello,Hi";
$partes = explode(",", $txt);
//$partes[0] = "Hola";
//$partes[1] = "Hello";
//$partes[2] = "Hi";
```

En tu caso necesitarías que se divida por salto de línea por lo que necesitas usar lo siguiente:
 `explode("\n", $txt);`

Comment: Sí, he usado explode dividiendo por salto de línea, sin embargo, si hay un texto que sea así:  
[Separador1]  (salto de línea)
Donec arcu quam, posuere non molestie eu, bibendum non enim. (salto de línea)
 [/Separador1]  

Cada línea se dividirá, y yo quiero que sea por todo el bloque [Separador1]...[/Separador1]

Comment: A que llamas [/Separador] ? Sino sería buscar el separador y tratarlo de esta manera.